# In how many ways we can insert records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dml

Like inserting single or multiple records at a time, one table data is inserting into another table with limited columns.

Comment: There is only one way: `INSERT`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is also bulk loading.

Comment: What about "Edit Top 200 Rows" @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen because of u i know the bulk loading

Comment: There is no [SQL statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/statements) named `Edit top 200 rows` - anything that a GUI offers (which I assume you are referring to with "Edit top ..") will eventually be carried out using an `INSERT` statement.

Comment: Whatever it is DML or GUI but need how many approaches we have

Comment: As I said: [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) is the approach to insert new rows

Comment: Thank You @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: pls see if this helps - https://msbiskills.com/2015/04/09/different-methods-to-insert-multiple-rows-using-single-insert-keyword/

Comment: This is what I am looking for thank you @PawanKumar and need from table to table insertion.

Comment: Glad to help always :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) four ways:

- [`INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql). Pretty obvious. It supports both single rows and multiple rows supplied as literal values, as well as inserting the result of a query or stored procedure.
- [`SELECT .. INTO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql) inserts the results of a query into a new table.
- [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql). Bulk inserts data from files. It's a little quirky and not very flexible when it comes to parsing files, but if you can get the data to line up it works well enough. Selecting data for bulk insert purposes can also be done with [`OPENROWSET(BULK, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql).
- [`INSERT BULK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd358082.aspx). This is an internal command that's used under the covers by drivers that use the bulk insert protocol in TDS (the protocol used by SQL Server). You do not issue these commands yourself. Unlike `BULK INSERT`, this is for client-side initiated bulk inserting, for example through the [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy)  class in .NET, or SQL Server's own [`bcp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/tools/bcp-utility) tool.

All other interfaces and approaches to inserting data use one of these methods  under the covers. Most of these will use plain old `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Bulk Insert
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql
2. Insert Transact
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql
3. Select Insert
   https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Hope this will help